# Performing raw sql query inside a model function?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a raw sql query that belongs to the Student model so i would like to create a function named get_student inside of our Student class and perform the query there instead of my view. How do i go about doing this?

With a view i would have done it this way:

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    query = "..." # complex query
    students_list = Student.objects.raw(query)
    # more code
```

model.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I tried doing the following:

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    Student.get_students()
```

model.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_students():
        query = "..." # complex query
        students = models.Manager.raw(query)
        return students
```

Error: unbound method get_students() must be called with Student instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    Student().get_students()
```

model.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_students(self):
        query = "..." # complex query
        students = self.objects.raw(query)
        return students
```

Error: Manager isn't accessible via Student instances

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    Student.get_students()
```

model.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_students(self):
        query = "..." # complex query
        students = models.Manager().raw(query)
        return students
```

Error: unbound method get_students() must be called with Student instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

view.py:

```
def index(request):
    Student().get_students()
```

model.py:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def get_students(self):
        query = "..." # complex query
        students = models.Manager().raw(query)
        return students
```

Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a Manager method.

```
class StudentManager(models.Manager):
    def get_students(self):
        query = "..." # complex query
        students = self.raw(query)

class Student(models.Model):
    ...
    objects = StudentManager()
```

...

```
students = Student.objects.get_students()
```

Comment: Ah! I was thinking of doing something like this but i wasn't sure if that was the "standard way". Is it? Edit: seems to be, thank you! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods

Comment: Yes definitely. Managers are the place to put query operations.